# Powershell - Get-ADComputer -properties memberof

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to find if any servers in our enviroment have NOT been applied to a particular group.
I have a list of groups that we use to patch our Windows Servers on partiular days / nights / manual etc..., i am trying to check if any server in our enviroment was incorrectly put on the domain and missed this step - does not have a Patching Group Member.

so far i i have:

```
$servers = get-adcomputer -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' -properties *
foreach ($server in $servers) {
   if($server.OperatingSystem -match "Windows Server 2008" -or $server.operatingsystem match "Windows Server 2003" ) {
   $server.Name, $server.OperatingSystem, $server.memberof
   }
}
```

Above lists all servers that run Windows in our enviroment and the Members assigned to that Computer Object. Say we have 3 particular groups that manage how these servers are patched.

group1, group2, group 3

Every server from the script above should return servers with group1, group2 or group3. I would like to return all the servers that DONT have group1, group2 or group3 applied.

Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Someone will beat me to it but you can combine your groups into a regex filter like the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069711/possible-to-combine-csv-where-object-filters). Also I would shorten your `If` like so `if($server.OperatingSystem -match "Windows Server 200[38]"` as it will match 2003 and 2008. You were missing a hyphen on your second match keyword

Comment: Also thank you for the comment, every tip and bits of advice helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's work with this:

```
$groups = @("Terminal Server License Servers","Exchange Trusted Subsystem","Cert Publishers")
$regex = '^({0})' -f ($groups -join '|')
get-adcomputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server 200*"} -properties * | 
    Where-Object{($_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).Name -notmatch $regex} |
    Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,MemberOf
```

Take the groups and turn them into an array. Join the array members into a regex string which will match the full names of groups. Move the `If` statement into a `-Filter` to return only what you want which would make it more efficient. The `MemberOf` is a list of `DistinguishedName`s. Get the just the group name from `Get-AdGroup`. You could easily use string manipulation to extract the name from the dn. I just find this easier. Havent done anything, beyond a `Select-Object`, with the results but you could pipe into a `ForEach-Object` and process accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation very helpful, i think i need to read more on up regular expressions. But that worked perfectly so thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```bsh
$servers = get-adcomputer -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' -properties * |
if($server.OperatingSystem -match "Windows Server 200[38]" | 
% { $_.Server } | select Domain,Name,Roles,OSVersion,IPAddress
```

## Provides only 2003 and 2008 matches filtering

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.
'

Answer (score -1):

[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites | if($server.OperatingSystem -match "Windows Server 200[38]"| % { $_.Server }

## | select Domain,Name,Roles,OSVersion,IPAddress