# Building a Powershell Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

[Link to Answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180988/powershell-get-adcomputer-properties-memberof/26181772#26181772)

In the link above there is a regex construct I am trying to figure out what the -f in it is doing. Appreciate your help.

Also, where can I find other regex parameters and other tutorial about regex. Any links please.

Thanks for reading and responding.

Comment: The -f is the Powershell -Format operator. It tells the shell to build the proceeding  string in accordance with the .Net String Formatting rules using the following variables. It doesn't directly have anything to do with the regex at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in learning Regex in Powershell,  lookup Mastering Powershell, and navigate to Chapter 14, Text and Regular Expressions.  It's sorta bare bones, but it's a start.

Comment: Should this really be an answer versus a comment?

Comment: I was trying to answer the request for another tutorial about Regex.

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 Regex Languages (An more I am not thinking of), and they are: PCRE/Javascript/Python. They regexs vary depending on which "Flavor" you use.

I suggest starting out by learning PCRE, because it is a very strong Flavor of Regex.

Here are some nice tutorials:

- http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/
- http://regexcrossword.com/