# PowerShell Not Member of Group

Tags: regex, powershell, filter

I'm looking at [Powershell - Get-ADComputer -properties memberof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180988/powershell-get-adcomputer-properties-memberof) and it's not working for me. The match always returns true. So I'll use something simple like Domain Computers in the group list and the `-notmatch` should filter out anything that is part of the Domain Computers group, well it still returns computers that are part of Domain Computers. All I want is a script that takes the computers and checks their membership against a list of groups and returns them if they are **not** part of that group list.

```
$groups = @("Terminal Server License Servers","Exchange Trusted Subsystem","Cert Publishers","Domain Computers")
$regex = '^({0})' -f ($groups -join '|')
get-adcomputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server 200*"} -properties * | Where-Object{($_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).Name -notmatch $regex} | Select-Object Name | fl
```

Comment: Can you show us your implementation of the attached code so we can better see what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: Please post the code that you are actually running not a link to another question. Please edit your question to provide this code. Do not post it as a comment.

Comment: That is the exact code from the answer in the linked question (except you dropped a couple of properties). You have changed nothing to make it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
Where-Object {-not (($_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).Name -match $regex) }
```

because `Y -notmatch X` does not mean "there is no Y that matches X" , it means "there is at least one Y that does not match X" (just as `Y -match X` does not mean "all Y match X", but "there is at least one Y that matches X")

You want the opposite of `Y -match X`, which is `-not (Y -match X)`.

Try

```
"a","3","#" -match "[a-z]"
"a","3","#" -notmatch "[a-z]"
```

to see what `-match` and `-notmatch` actually do.

---

Via the chat the OP and me found a better solution to the problem, repeated here for convenience:

> We are comparing two lists here - the group memberships of the
>   ADComputer and your reference list, and you want to eliminate all
>   where there is at least one match, and show the rest.
>
> So, for each computer object, for each group that it is a member of,
>   if that group appears in your reference list, filter out the computer.
>
> PowerShell Code:
>
> ```
> $referenceListOfGroups =
>     "CN=group_1....",
>     "CN=group_2....",
>     "CN=group_N...."
>
> Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "OperatingSystem=Windows Server 200*" -Properties MemberOf | Where-Object {
>     ($_.MemberOf | Where-Object { $_ -in $referenceListOfGroups }).Count -eq 0
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Even with the changes it still isn't working. I think it's because in the group name there is parenths which is throwing off the matching. Is there a way I could make it ignore that in the string? `$groups = @("server - (number) Extra text")`

Comment: New issue - I got it to ignore the regex characters in the string, but now when I introduce multiple groups to check against, it doesn't work `$groups = [regex]::escape(@("server - (1) Extra Text","server - (2) Extra Text"))`

Comment: I'd recommend that instead of regex you use an array of *actual* group names and the `-in` operator: `-not (($_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).Name -in $groups)`

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. Still isn't working. When you say actual group names, I'm assuming you mean the group name, not the full CN name right?

Comment: Yes, the group name, since that is what `($_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).Name` produces. You can use the full name of you also use `($_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).DistinguishedName`.

Comment: Ok. I'm definitely using the group name returned by `($_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup).Name ` in my `$group` array. Now it returns multiple groups in braces `{Group 1, Group 2}` for each server. That shouldn't be an issue though as it should look at all groups returned and compare them to the array right?

Comment: Okay, let's back up a little - what exactly do you mean by *"a script that takes the computers and checks their membership against a list of groups and returns them if they are not part of that group list."*? Is this "I want all computers that are not in *all* of the lists? Or those that are missing in *one* of them?

Comment: I have a list of about 50 groups and a list of computers. I want to check my list of computers and make sure they are in at least 1 of the groups. If they are in one of the groups, great, I don't need to know. I need to know which computers are NOT in any of the groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174736/discussion-between-tomalak-and-user3498593).